# Traer hasta 3 resultados de un campo id

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Me surgio un problema, tengo que mostrar hasta un limite de 3 resultados de un mismo user_id y no he encontrado alguna funcion o algo que puede decirle a la consulta que me traiga 3 resultados del mismo user_id y luego siga con otro.

Tabla users_establishments
Columnas: id,user_id,establishment_id

Por ejemplo en la foto adjunta me tendria que traer 3 filas del que tiene user_id = 1 en vez de 4 resultados y luego mostrar los otros de manera iterativa hasta un maximo de 3 resultados por user_id

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano

[image]

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_establishments` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`establishment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

INSERT INTO `users_establishments` (`id`, `user_id`, `establishment_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL),
(2, 2, 2, NULL, NULL),
(3, 3, 3, NULL, NULL),
(4, 4, 4, NULL, NULL),
(5, 5, 5, NULL, NULL),
(6, 1, 5, NULL, NULL),
(7, 1, 2, NULL, NULL),
(8, 1, 3, NULL, NULL);

Comment: Agrega por favor aquello que hayas intentado

Comment: Deberias publicar el script de creacion de tabla y el de poblado de datos

Comment: @MauricioOrtega Listo

Comment: @BetaM literal que no he hecho nada mas que la estructura base SELECT user_id, establishment_id FROM users_establishments; porque me tranque en decirle que me traiga solo 3 de esa consulta

Comment: Eso lo puedo entener y no hay mayor problema con ello, pero para poderte dar una respuesta funcional ocupamos saber por ejemplo ¿qué criterior se debe seguir para saber de 5 registros asociados al usuario con id 1, cuáles debe tomar y cuales no?

Comment: @BetaM Seleccionando cualquier fila seria suficiente siempre y cuando sean hasta 3 resultados devueltos por useri_id .

Comment: Entonces si no hay regla para delimitar que resultados traer de ese id entonces al final solo ponle `LIMIT 3`

Comment: @BetaM si te refieres a esta consulta SELECT user_id, establishment_id FROM users_establishments LIMIT 3; solo me trae 3 filas pero no del mismo usuario y tampoco todos los que hay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede realizarse consultando sobre una tabla derivada en la que se genere un consecutivo particionado con la funcion ROW_NUMBER (Pero solo a partir de MySql 8)

```
select *
  from (select c.id,c.user_id,
               c.establishment_id,
               c.created_at,c.updated_at
              ,row_number() over (partition by c.user_id order by c.id) as ridusr -- columna que genera el consecutivo particionado
          from users_establishments as c ) as d
  where d.ridusr<=3 -- filtra las filas
```

Comment: Deberías aclararle desde que versión funciona row_number, ya que si el mysql que usa es inferior al 8 esa sentencia no funcionará

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me sirvio a la perfeccion sos un capo loco <3

Comment: @BetaM gracias por la ayuda, tendre en cuenta eso de la version.